# Php Curl Post form data sign-up

Tags: php, http, curl, post

I am doing a auto sign-up. And posting form data with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. 
I have 4 data to post. But Response always says 3. and 4. "This field is required.". So if username is first ok it posted but if it is 3. doesnt post.

Example:

```
$form_values = http_build_query( array('username' => $this->username, 'email'=> $this->email, 'password'=> $this->pass,  'first_name' => $this->name) );
```

post username and email. Given error about password and first name.

```
$form_values = http_build_query( array('email'=> $this->email, 'password'=> $this->pass,  'username' => $this->username, 'first_name' => $this->name) );
```

post email and pass only.

How can be posible. I already try write post data manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a possible try is

1. curl_setopt($curlobj, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/mytest.php');
2. in mytest.php  var_dump($_POST);
3. check the post if it is right, maybe the problem is target form
4. fix post url of target form to http://localhost/mytest.php in
   firebug or chrome check the post

Comment: Thanks buddy. It was all about header: content length.